# Why $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}=\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X]$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X:(\Omega ,\mathcal A)\to (D,\mathcal D)$ and $Y:(\Omega ,\mathcal A)\to (E,\mathcal E)$ two random variables. Let $\mathcal G,\mathcal H\subset \mathcal F$ independent sub-field s.t. $X$ is $\mathcal G/\mathcal D$ measurable, $Y$ is $\mathcal H/\mathcal E$ measurable.

I proved that $$\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid \mathcal F]=[\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]]\mid_{x=X}.$$

After they say, this prove that  $$\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid \mathcal F]=[\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]]\mid_{x=X}=\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X],$$
but I can't prove the last equality (and it's not proved in my book). Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x)=\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]$. This is a measurable function. What you proved is $$\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid \mathcal F]=f(X),$$ and thus $\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid \mathcal F]$ is $\sigma (X)-$measurable. This prove that 
$$\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid \mathcal F]=\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid \sigma (X)]=\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X].$$

Comment: Thank you but why  your function $f$ is measurable ?

Comment: Set $g(x,\omega )=\Phi(x,Y(\omega ))$. You can write $g$ as $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{finite}\varphi _k(x)\psi_k(\omega )$. The claim almost follow.

Comment: If you want to provide a more detail answer, see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318122/why-fx-mathbb-e-phix-y-is-mesurable-if-phi-is-measurable). Thank you.