# Why $f(x)=\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]$ is mesurable if $\Phi$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

The question come from Surb answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318112/why-mathbb-e-phix-y-x-x-mathbb-e-phix-y-mid-x/3318115?noredirect=1#comment6826799_3318115). I'm making a new question because I would like to have a more detailed answer. So let $\Phi :D\times E\to \mathbb R$ measurable where $(D,\mathcal F)$, $(E,\mathcal E)$ are measure space. Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $Y:A\to E$ measurable. Why $$x\mapsto \mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]$$ is measurable. According to Surb, this come from the fact that $g(x,\omega )=\Phi(x,Y(\omega ))$ is measuable, and thus can be written as $$g(x,\omega )=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{finite}\varphi _k(x)\psi_k(\omega ),$$
where $\varphi _k$ and $\psi_k$ are meaurable. Honnestly, I don't understand the argument. Could someone provides more explanation ?

Comment: I don't understand Surb's argument either.

Answer (score 1):

Part of Fubini/Tonelli's Theoerm says that if you take a measurable function on a product space and integrate w.r.t one variable then the resulting function is measurable w.r.t.  the remaining variable. $E\Phi(x,Y)$ is integral of $\Phi(x,y)$ w.r.t. the distribution of $Y$ so it is measurable if $\Phi(x,Y(\omega))$ is measurable.

So it is enough to show that $\Phi(x,Y(\omega))$ is measurable. This function is the composition of the measurable functions $(x,\omega) \to (x,Y(\omega))$ and the function $\Phi$. (To see that the $(x,\omega) \to (x,Y(\omega)$ is measurable write down the inverse image of  measurable rectangle).